# fastest way to select 7*7 neighbor pixels for every pixel in an image in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, scikit-image

need to read an image as an array and for each pixel select 7*7 neighbor pixels then reshape it and put as a first row of training set:

```
  import numpy as np
  from scipy import misc
  face1=misc.imread('face1.jpg')
```

`face1` dimensions are `(288, 352, 3)` , need to find 7*7 neighbor pixels for every pixel , so 49*3 color then reshape it as a `(1,147)` array and stack it into an array for all pixels , i took the following approach:

```
X_training=np.zeros([1,147] ,dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(3, face1.shape[0]-3):
    for j in range(3, face1.shape[1]-3):
        block=face1[i-3:i+4,j-3:j+4]
        pxl=np.reshape(block,(1,147))
        X_training=np.vstack((pxl,X_training))
```

resulting `X_training` shape is `(97572, 147)`

and as last row contains all zeros then:

```
a = len(X_training)-1
X_training = X_training[:a]
```

above code works well for one picture but with `Wall time: 5min 19s` i have 2000 images, so it will take ages to do it for all the images. I am looking for a faster way to iterate over every pixel and do the above task.

Edit: [image]
this is what i mean by neighbor pixels , for every pixel `face1[i-3 : i+4 ,j-3:j+4]`

Comment: could you break the image into chunks and work different sections with threads or something along those lines?

Comment: I do not really understand which neighboring pixels you want to select. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Jacobr365 do not have required skill to do that

Comment: Also, how do you want to handle the edges of the image?

Comment: Think it should be : `X_training=np.zeros([0,147] ,dtype=np.uint8)`.

Comment: @jotasi edited the post

Comment: @2cynykyl  that is why i started from 3 and end at face1.shape[0]-3

Comment: @Divakar it has nothing to do with running time

Comment: @sanaz It has do with confusing people, because you would have the last row of output as all zeros and as such that row doesn't deal with selecting neighbours. People need to understand what you are doing.

Comment: @Divakar  I made an edit, but as the title of question and explanation says i am looking for a way to faster the process, even if one row is all zero.

Comment: Well the title says - `to select 7*7 neighbor pixels for every pixel ..`. With that all zeros row, it might confuse people. Apologies if my tone sounded too picky, just trying to be see a good question here.

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925684/generalize-stacking-of-array-elements-neighbors-into-3-d-array

Comment: @Divakar any idea how can i do exactly same task in pyspark? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400235/fastest-way-to-select-77-neighbor-pixels-for-every-pixel-in-an-image-in-pyspark

Comment: @sanaz Sorry, nope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An efficient way is to use `stride_tricks` to create a 2d rolling window over the image, then flatten it out:

```
import numpy as np

face1 = np.arange(288*352*3).reshape(288, 352, 3)  # toy data

n = 7  # neighborhood size

h, w, d = face1.shape
s = face1.strides

tmp = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(face1, strides=s[:2] + s,
                                      shape=(h - n + 1, w - n + 1, n, n, d))
X_training = tmp.reshape(-1, n**2 * d)
X_training = X_training[::-1]  # to get the rows into same order as in the question
```

`tmp` is a 5D view into the image, where `tmp[x, y, :, :, c]` is equivalent to the neigborhood `face1[x:x+n, y:y+n, c]` in color channel `c`.

Comment: Good one! To replicate the output from OP, we would need a flipping there along rows.

Comment: @Right, Thank you. I've added this as an explicit step because I'm not very fond of negative strides :)

Comment: I have never heard of strides before, but after a bit of reading I see that I've been missing out on some powerful stuff...thanks!

Comment: @2cynykyl good to hear.. I also learned about strides on this site.

Comment: @kazemakase any idea how can i do exactly same task in pyspark? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400235/fastest-way-to-select-77-neighbor-pixels-for-every-pixel-in-an-image-in-pyspark

Comment: @sanaz no, sorry. I do not know anything about pyspark.

Answer (score 3):

The following is < 1s on my laptop:

```
import scipy as sp
im = sp.rand(300, 300, 3)

size = 3
ij = sp.meshgrid(range(size, im.shape[0]-size), range(size, im.shape[1]-size))
i = ij[0].T.flatten()
j = ij[1].T.flatten()

N = len(i)
L = (2*size + 1)**2
X_training = sp.empty(shape=[N, 3*L])

for pixel in range(N):
    si = (slice(i[pixel]-size, i[pixel]+size+1))
    sj = (slice(j[pixel]-size, j[pixel]+size+1))
    X_training[pixel, :] = im[si, sj, :].flatten()

X_training = X_training[-1::-1, :]
```

I'm always a bit sad when I can't think of one-line vectorized version, but at least it's faster for you.

Comment: can you compare your answer with best answer? it does not return the same result. there should be some mistake somewhere , my own approach and best answer return exactly same result

Comment: I've updated my answer, and it now produces the same output as @kazemakase.  The rows were were in a different ordering, so I transposed  the ``ij`` array, and I also reversed the overall order of the rows in the final answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using scikit-image:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import util

image = np.random.random((288, 352, 3))
windows = util.view_as_windows(image, (7, 7, 3))

out = windows.reshape(-1, 7 * 7 * 3)
```

Comment: +1 for using skimage...but I just read the docs for this ``view_as_window`` function and it's has terrible performance issues!  Someone should really re-implement it using the ``stride_tricks`` in the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; it *does* use strides: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/util/shape.py#L107

Comment: my apologies for not checking source...but the docstring really makes it sounds like it is creating new copies of the array, and that memory can get explosively large.  My understanding of strides is that it provides new 'views'  onto a single copy of the underlying data, hence no copies and much faster.  How does your answer compare to @kazemakase in terms of speed I wonder?

Comment: It'd be great if you could compare!  We'd be very happy for PRs to improve the documentation or implementation.